# Headphones do not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, headphones

I'm an user in Ubuntu, and I have a problem with my headphone. The sound is good but it's not working when I use headphones. I make sure that headphone is good to use.

Can anyone  help me with information in this link: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=975e7e00ceef0e1fcc5dd3176e18a76f793cbac9

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to try. First, check your headphones are not muted and the volume is up. In a terminal type `alsamixer` then in the terminal GUI that opens check your headphone volume.

Comment: i used to try it but not successful, can you tell me another way to fix it.

Comment: Try and re install pulseaudio. I know it sounds overkill but cured all manner of audio ills for me.